# How can I add a button in the center of a RepositoryItem in a column of a devexpress datagrid?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I want to add a button with an image in the middle of a cell in a column of a devexpress datagrid.

The click event should be triggered only when pressing the button and not the entire cell.

How can I add a button only in the center of an editor?

Comment: Do you still need to edit text in a cell?

Comment: No, only a button in the middle of the repositoryitem

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a RepositoryItemButtonEdit? Assign it to the necessary GridColumn.ColumnEdit property.